# Using Taylor series to find an integral over a particular range

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

Well, I want to solve:

$$\int_0^x\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(t\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}t\tag1$$

Using a Taylor series.

I know that, the taylor series looks like (series expansion at $t=0$):

$$\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(t\right)\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\right)^2}+\frac{\epsilon t^2}{\left(1+\epsilon\right)^3}+\dots\tag2$$

But that series has to be convergent for a value that is at least equal to $x$, to be able to solve the integral using that series.

> But how can find if the series is convergent for a value that is al least equal to $x$, or should I pick another value to find the expansion at (now I've $t=0$ but what is the consequence, for the convergence, when I choose $t=1$ or $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$)? For $\epsilon\approx0.0167086$

Comment: That is the area of an elliptic sector (delimited by two rays emanating from a focus) with a rather involved closed form. Taylor series are definitely not the way to devise such closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that

$$\frac1{(1-r)^2}=1+2r+3r^2+4r^3+\dots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)r^k$$

converges for $|r|<1$, and since $|\epsilon\cos(t)|<1$ for $|\epsilon|<1$, we have

$$\frac1{(1+\epsilon\cos(t))^2}=1-2\epsilon\cos(t)+3\epsilon^2\cos^2(t)-\dots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)\epsilon^k\cos^k(t)$$

Thus,

$$\int_0^x\frac1{(1+\epsilon\cos(t))^2}\ dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)\epsilon^k\int_0^x\cos^k(t)\ dt$$

In terms of the [hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html),

$$\int_0^x\cos^k(t)\ dt=\frac{-x|\sin(x)|\cos^{k+1}(x)\csc(x)_2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac{1+k}2;\frac{3+k}2;\cos^2(x)\right)}{1+k}$$

At least according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=0&y=0&i=int%20(cos(x))%5Ek).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so it converges for every value of $t$?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.